# C ­function declaration in a parameter list

Tags: c++, c, function

I'm find out a bit confusing thing in C code

```
struct SomeStruct {
    // ...
    void (*f)(const void *x);
};

void do_some( void f(const void *x) ) { // what?
    struct SomeStruct* v;
    // ...
    v->f = f;
}
```

As I can understand `do_some` take function instead function pointer.
But what is difference with `void do_some( void (*f)(const void *x) )` in practice? When I should use this? Is this allowed in C++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference. It's just syntactic sugar. It is allowed in both C and C++.

Function parameters are simply rewritten by the compiler as function pointer parameters, just as array parameters are rewritten by the compiler as pointer parameters.

For reference, here is an excerpt from the C standard, section 3.7.1:

```
g(int (*funcp)(void))

// ...

or, equivalently, 

g(int func(void))
```

Comment: Just a q sir, `v->f = f;` is that allowed? I mean the function return types are different, right?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Edited.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Both functions return `void`.

Comment: @fredoverflow Not before the edit, when the comment was made.

Comment: the transformation by the compiler to a function pointer does not happen by a typedef, am I right? so a `using f = void(int)` isn't equal to a `using f = void(*)(int)`?

Comment: Correct, it only happens for function parameters.

Comment: You can actually invoke *any* function this way! try this: `int main(void) { (***printf)("Hello world\n"); }`

Answer (score 4):

> As I can understand `do_some` take function instead function pointer.

No, as a function parameter a function type is adjusted to the corresponding function pointer type. The argument `f` has the same function pointer type as the member `f`.

> But what is difference with void `do_some( void (*f)(const void *x) )` in practice?

None whatsoever.

> When I should use this?

If you like extra verbosity. Or in other contexts, such as declarations, where you need to distinguish function and pointer types.

> Is this allowed in C++?

For function parameters (and also non-type template parameters) the same adjustment is applied in C++.